# How to access the dom of a body using window.location.href

Tags: javascript

I am looking at a package (https://github.com/officert/vue-friendly-iframe) which includes the following code:

```
function setIframeUrl() {
  var iframeDoc = this.iframeEl.contentWindow.document;
  iframeDoc.open().write(
    '<body onload="window.location.href=\'' + this.src + '\'; parent.postMessage(
       \'' + this.iframeLoadedMessage + '\', \'*\')">
     </body>
     <script>\n window.document.onreadystatechange = function () {
       if(window.document.readyState === \'complete\') {
         parent.postMessage(\'' + this.iframeOnReadyStateChangeMessage + '\', \'*\')
       }};
     </script>'
  );

  iframeDoc.close();
},
```

Is there a non-hack way to use javascript to access the HTML <body> tag of the document being loaded at that url?

Example: If the contents at the url of this.src contained

```
<html>
  <body class="foo">
    Hello World
  </body>
</html>
```

I would like to get the body tag and then change the class from 'foo' to 'bar'.

Comment: Pick your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `DOMParser`.

```js
let response = `
<html>
  <body class="foo">
    Hello World
  </body>
</html>`;

const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString(response, "text/html");

doc.body.classList.remove('foo');
doc.body.classList.add('bar');

console.log(doc.documentElement.outerHTML);
```

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser

Comment: Thanks! How do I get the response object from the onLoad call?

Comment: For a different question, ask a different question.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but it was part of the original question. I just wrote some html as an example of what could be at that url. I edited the OP a couple days ago to better convey that